# Why does my ES6 Promise Rejection need to be consumed immediately to avoid a console error message?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Please note:  The following is an issue that behaves differently on different browsers.  So perhaps this is a browser implementation issue.  I would love some advice regardless.

In my application, I am creating a couple of promises that I may not be consuming until quite some time in the future.  Which should be fine, they are promises, after all.

If the promise being stored away is resolved, there is no issue.  I can consume it as far in the future as I want, and as many times as I want.  As expected.

If the promise being stored away is rejected, however, there is an issue.  Unless I consume that rejection shortly after it is made (not sure how shortly) a console message will crop up in Chrome or Firefox indicating that there is an uncaught promise rejection/error.  IE does not pop up that error.

So consider the following code:

```
console.log("About to make a promise rejection.");
var foo = Promise.reject(new Error("Foo Rejected Promise."));
console.log("Promise rejection made.");
```

Note that there is no use or consumption of the promise foo.  It is merely stored away for some future use.

The console on IE looks like this:

> About to make a promise rejection.
>
> Promise rejection made.

Which is expected.  However, the same code on Chrome will yield the following console:

> About to make a promise rejection.
>
> Promise rejection made.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Foo Rejected Promise.(…)

Firefox looks pretty much like Chrome, other than the wording around the "uncaught" error.

But the thing is that I intend to handle this "error" much later, at the time I am consuming the promise.  Merely HAVING a rejected promise should not cause a console error..... that should happen if I **consume** the promise and don't handle the error.

To simulate a "much later" handling of the error, consider this alteration of the code:

```
console.log("About to make a promise rejection.");
var foo = Promise.reject(new Error("Foo Rejected Promise."));
console.log("Promise rejection made.");
setTimeout(() => {
    foo.catch((err) => {
        console.log("Displaying " + err.message + " 10 seconds later.");
    });
}, 10000);
```

Now in this case, we "handle" the error by displaying something on the console after a timeout.  Now IE still handles this as I would expect:

> About to make a promise rejection.
>
> Promise rejection made.
>
> Displaying Foo Rejected Promise. 10 seconds later.

In this case, Firefox does like IE, and displays exactly these messages, and does not give me an erroneous console error.

Chrome, however, still gives the erroneous error:

> About to make a promise rejection.
>
> Promise rejection made.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Foo Rejected Promise.(…)
>
> Displaying Foo Rejected Promise. 10 seconds later.

So Chrome both complained about my error not being handled, and then displayed that it was handled.

It appears that I can get around all this with the following code that that seems like a hack.  Basically I do a "fake" handling of the error when the promise is created and then really handle it the way I want to later:

```
console.log("About to make a promise rejection.");
var foo = Promise.reject(new Error("Foo Rejected Promise."));
foo.catch(() => { });  // Added this hack-ish code.
console.log("Promise rejection made.");
    setTimeout(() => {
    foo.catch((err) => {
        console.log("Displaying " + err.message + " 10 seconds later.");
    });
}, 10000);
```

But this is ugly code.

My question is twofold - is there some way of looking at what Chrome (and to some extent FireFox) is doing and think of it as a favor?  Because to me it seems awful.  And secondly, is there a better way of getting around this than the hack of pretending to handle an error when you aren't?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 99.99% of the time when a promise rejects and there is no rejection handler at that time, this is an uncaught rejection.  When that legitimately happens, this is a silent, but serious programming error and thus some makers have decided that this should be logged.  The way you are doing things (attaching a reject handler after the fact) is highly unusual.  There's nothing wrong with it, but it is the 0.01% case.  So, some makers have decided to log this situation because 99.99% of the time it is an indication of a serious error and it's difficult for them to discern the difference.

Comment: In the second case, Firefox nightly behaves like Chrome, not like IE. And my intuition says that's the proper way.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to tell the JS engine that you know what you're doing so please turn this warning off, perhaps on a promise-by-promise basis since what is desired in one case is not desired in most cases.  It can be a very useful warning in most situations.

Comment: I spent some time boiling this down.  In my actual case, I am creating the promise in the constructor of an object so that I can then refer to the promise when I later call a prototype method on the object and need the result of the promise.  So yes, it would be very nice to be able to tell the engine please don't log this!

Comment: I don't understand why you say "*pretending to handle an error when you aren't*". You want to ignore the error, and that's a way of handling it.

Comment: Well this is just wording.  I don't want to ignore the error.  I don't intend to ignore the error.  I just want to handle the error when I am consuming the promise, not when I am creating the promise.  It seems I have to fake the JS engine into thinking I am handling the error when the promise is created so that I can avoid the logging of a non-problem and really handle the error (as intended) when the promise is consumed.

Comment: The behavior you want is what observables give you (RxJS)

Comment: After you later handle the error, I believe Chrome's web console will retroactively move the "uncaught" error back into a category of "caught" errors, in all displays, a bit of a neat trick, so they are at least aware of your use case. Still a pain if you break on them though. Firefox will only report the error as uncaught once all references to it are gone, which I believe is the right approach (though I think it currently waits several seconds until garbage collection which could be improved).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but in my case I'm running unit tests, and I want to catch the rejected promise in the "Then" clause instead of the "When". This is mostly an issue with how Cucumber sets up tests, but because it's breaking on this uncaught error, my test which catches it never occurs.

So while I could do `Promise.reject().catch(() => {})`, I wouldn't also be able to verify in my test that there was an error message and that the error message matches what I'm testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any promise that has a chance to be rejected, should be handled, similarly to exceptions.

There are not so many chances that a promise won't be chained synchronously. But if it won't, it requires 'hack-ish' `.catch(() => { })` to synchronously handle the rejection.

Chrome promise rejection behaviour puts this

```
var foo = Promise.reject(new Error("Foo Rejected Promise."));
foo.catch(() => { });  // Added this hack-ish code.

setTimeout(() => {
    foo.catch((err) => {
        console.log("Displaying " + err.message + " 10 seconds later.");
    });
}, 10000);
```

into the same error-handling boat as

```
try {
  throw new Error("Foo"));

  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error("Foo"));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Displaying " + err.message + " 10 seconds later.");
    }
  }, 10000);
} catch (err) {}
```

Wouldn't the exception wait 10 seconds to be caught by next `try...catch` before being thrown? It won't wait even a single tick. It requires 'hack-ish' `try { ... } catch (err) {}` block to perform as intended.

This behaviour is already well-known to Bluebird library users for quite a long time. Bluebird has adjustable error handling and allows to [debug promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html) efficiently even on the large scale.

The behaviour is also known in Angular 2 development, it is forced for promises with Zone.js library.

Since promise debugging has limited value and applicable to development environment, it is possible to modify or disable this behaviour for native promises in production builds:

```
if (typeof DEBUG_PROMISE === 'undefined') {
  window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.warn(e.reason);
  });
}
```

[Here's more reading](http://www.2ality.com/2016/04/unhandled-rejections.html) on the subject.

Comment: This is a good answer, and the listener you referred to is great information.  As is the "further reading".  Thank you for taking this time.  I would argue that Chrome would do better to set the default the other way, but at least I have a way to make this operate properly.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who has worked with promises for a couple of years now, I understand why this behavior is set in Chrome. it is easy to forget to catch a rejected promise, and if there is an error in .then(), there will be no notification and your program will just stay silent blankly. It can be very hard to debug.

```
function throwException(c){ return a.b = 2 ;} //a is not defined. throws exception.
let p = q.resolve("a")
         .then(x => x + "b")
         .then(y => throwException(y))
         .then(z=> z+"c");   //this will say nothing in Q library
```

this can easily create a very obscure behaviour when one forgets to catch the error.

In Q library, you have the .done() function to actually enforce what Chrome is doing here:

```
let p = q.resolve("a")
         .then(x => x + "b")
         .then(y => throwException(y))
         .then(z=> z+"c")
         .done();   //this will throw an exception.
```

So, it is a known problem in promises. Chrome have simply decided to make .done() the default behavior, asking you to explicitly `.catch(_=>{})` if you want to ignore failed promises. Q has decided to make silent failure default, asking you to explicitly use `.done()` if you want an exception on failed promise. If you like the latter approach, you can always include a promise library. It is a matter of taste IMHO.